# How to print out the differences between two text (Python)

Tags: python, difference

My code is like this :

```
text1 = "I like apple"
text2 = "I like car"
if text1 != text2:
   print "the differences are:"the_difference
```

The output should be:

```
the differences are:car
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: What if text2 was `text2 = "An apple I like"`. Should it print `the differences are: an apple`?

Comment: Split the two sentences on whitespace then compare 1 list against the other

Comment: @Matheus208  that is what I mean

Comment: @ZeroX Just wondering. If the order mattered, then the solution would be different.

Comment: If as @Matheus208 said, then the answer maybe little difficult...and maybe there is a module can do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 = "I like apple"
text2 = "I like car"
set1 = set(text1.split())
set2 = set(text2.split())
diffs = set1.symmetric_difference(set2)
```

Comment: @ZeroX But if `text2` was `text2 = "An apple I like"`. This doesn't print `the differences are: an apple`, it only prints `{'An'}`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Yes that is what I want